# Get record in between dates

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Table : ras_attrecord Field : Clock (date time)

Table : staff_shift Fields: startdate (datetime), enddate (datetime)

Scenario

In my table there are multiple records of Time In and Time out. In order to get the timein, it will depend on the staff shift. for example, my shift is 2013-11-05 09:00:00 and my first time in is 2013-11-05 08:54:00 and i time in again 2013-11-05 08:55:00. Next, my end shift is 2013-11-05 18:00:00 andI exit the office at 2013-11-05 17:00:00 and again I time out 2013-11-05- 17:01:00... there are multiple records

```
2013-11-05 08:54:00 - First Time In
2013-11-05 08:55:00 - Second Time In 
2013-11-05 08:54:00 - First Time Out 
2013-11-05 08:55:00 - Second Time Out
```

My problem is i need a mysql query to get the first time in and the first time out... sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question makes no sense. You know exactly how to get it. You need to do a better job explaining what you really need.

Comment: does ...14:30... exist in your database? Can you select it with a simpler query like `"SELECT Clock from ras_attrecord WHERE Clock = '2013-05-01 14:30:00'"`?

Comment: for example, 

2013-05-01 09:00:00 -> Time in 
2013-05-01 14:30:00 -> Time Out
2013-05-01 17:30:00 -> Time Out

I need to get the first timeout..

Comment: Is there any column exists in table which store 'time-in' or 'time-out' ??

Comment: Allen Chak, there is no column for time in time out. and they dont want to add that. i already suggested it but still they dont want it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the second record by adding:

```
limit 1, 1
```

to the end of your query.

Comment: Thanks. but did that too..

for example, 

2013-05-01 09:00:00 -> Time in 
2013-05-01 14:30:00 -> Time Out
2013-05-01 17:30:00 -> Time Out

I need to get the first timeout..